# What regex pattern can I use to match multiple instances of a variable sequence, and still include all the remaining chars?

Tags: regex

The data:

```
"things/groups/%S<match_00>/colors/%S<match_01>/details"
```

trying this pattern:

```
(.*?)(%S<)(.*?)(>)(.*?)
```

it finds both "match_00" and "match_01" but excludes the ending "/details"

trying this pattern:

```
(.*?)(%S<)(.*?)(>)(.*)
```

it includes the entire string but only finds the first "match_00"

trying this pattern:

```
(.*?)(%S<)(.*)(>)(.*)
```

it includes the entire string but thinks everything between "match_00" and "match_01" are a single group

trying this pattern:

```
(.*)(%S<)(.*)(>)(.*)
```

it includes the entire string but only finds the seconds "match_01"

Comment: You can try: `%S<([^>]*)>|([^<>]*)$`

Answer (score 0):

Your match requires the to be markup, but the last match doesn't have any, so add an alternation for the tail:

```
(.+?)%S<(.+?)>|(.+?)$
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/lKiKuIPhxWb4No).

---

Note also that you don't need to, and shouldn't, capture constants eg `(>)` always matches `>`, so there's no point in capturing it but the extra brackets just bloat the regex making it harder to read.